# ImageButton - how to read the image ID?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imagebutton

Sorry for the banal question, but I'm new to Android. I have such a problem. I have several ImageButton elements and I need to change their images depending on what is on them during onClick() event. While setting a new image is not a problem, I can not programmatically read what image is currently (the next image depends on it).I search various sources and can't find a solution. It is certainly very simple.

I want to have a code like this:

```
if (ImageButton1.image... == R.drawable.img1)
{
   ImageButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2)
   ImageButton2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3)
   ...
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to get over this is have an Int array and store the drawables in the array in the format

```
var listOfImages = listOf<Int>(R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two)
```

Now set the images as  ImageButton1.setImageResource(listOfImages(0))

That way you know which drawablr is being used